# How to "reload" a page after captcha has been solved manually in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am running a puppeteer script which does automated checkouts. I am running into captcha problems every now and then. The way I want to work around this is to manually solve the captcha and let my script continue from the page which comes AFTER I have solved the captcha.

Psuedocode

```
 Puppeteer script is working (headless:false) ....
 Captcha appears on my chromium screen
 I solve it manually and the next screen appears (Which would happen if there were no captcha)
 Help=> Puppeteer picks up the "current" (post-captcha) page and continues execution....
```

Is this possible and how? Thanks!!

Comment: Is the page reloaded after captcha solved?

Comment: Yes, the page is reloaded once I solve Captcha...

Comment: try to use page.waitForNavigation then

Comment: That doesn't work...the page moves on while I solve the captcha

Comment: Then you need to wait for some changes on the page that occur after solving Captcha